# Zend Frameworks

Tags: zend-framework

i am new to zend frameworks and i want to know links or tutorial to start zend frameworks.I use deepblue online tutorial to learn but they are not apt 
for beginners.So please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is for specific programming related questions as defined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: for zend tutorial check the link http://zenddevelopment.blogspot.in/. You can ask the questions also and you can get the class over skype here. The answer and solution will be provide you here quickly.

Comment: Zend provides comprehensive documentation for their framework. Start [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html) and work your way through.

Comment: http://www.zendcasts.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend http://phpdev.ro/zf-tutorial-series-part-1-module-based-app.html, it covers a lot:

1. Setting up a module based application
2. Setting up helper plugins, methods & debugging with ZFDebug
3. Setting up a login page and signup page with captcha
4. Setting up OpenID to login/create account
5. Setting up an API to create/login an account
6. Improving performance implementing Zend Cache

otherwise check a ton of videos on youtube
http://www.google.ca/search?q=youtube+zend+framework+getting+started

Answer (score 1):

I would Suggest you to learn the Object Oriented Programming And Model View Controller First. But If U have these Skills U Must Read following Articles which is mention below:
This is the quick Start to understand the zend framework methodlogy.

[Quick Start About Zend Framework Methodlogy](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html)

[Beginning Zend Framework (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218258)